# Solving a polynomial equation using substitution

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, substitution

The equation is:
$x^4 + 4x^2 + 16 = 0$

I tried solving it by substitution and then using the quadratic formula:
$x^2 = a$

$a^2 + 4a + 16 = 0$

using the quadratic formula I got $a = -2 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}$,

so $x = \pm \sqrt{-2 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}}$

But, the actual solution does not use substitution and has different results:
$x^4 + 4x^2 + 16 = (x^2 + 2x + 4)(x^2 - 2x + 4)$

$$ x = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4-4(4)(1)}}{2} = \frac{-2 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}}{2} = - 1 \pm i\sqrt{3}$$

and

$$ x = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4-4(4)(1)}}{2} = \frac{2 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}}{2} = 1 \pm i\sqrt{3}$$

So, the answer is $\pm 1 \pm i \sqrt{3}$

The question is, why was my approach wrong?

Comment: Your approach is not wrong, and (unless I am mistaken), the four possible values of $ \pm \sqrt{-2 \pm 2i\sqrt{3}}$ are equal to $\pm 1 \pm i \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Your answer is correct (it gives equivalent values), but be sure to check with your teacher if you can include a $±$ within a square root.

Comment: You have $x^2=a=-2\pm 2\sqrt{3}i$.

Let $x=m+in$. Then squaring and comparing real and imaginary parts, $(m^2-n^2)=-2$ and $2mn=\pm 2\sqrt{3}$. You can solve it for $m$ and $n$.